# how to update google sheets append_row formula in python?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

hello I am stopping my project

google sheet update row through python

I want to data and formulae (sum/average..etc)

I try to execute python code

```
self.kuf_worksheet_history.append_row(['',self.today, gamemap, '1500',yourace, yourname, myname, myrace,'=D10+D10'])
```

and this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SljbD.png)

formular column click detail

```
'=D10+D10
```

I want to `googlesheet.append_row()`, how to upadte data witch formular?

Please answer and thank your for watching my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are using the [`spreadsheet.values`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)  if you looking in the documentation for [this guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing) you can see that it explains how by default the formula values are parses as string.

If you want to avoid that and make them formulas use the value
`USER_ENTERED` for the parameter [`ValueInputOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption).

There is even a snippet of code in the previous linked guide to show how that would be done:

```py
values = [
    [
        # Cell values ...
    ],
    # Additional rows ...
]
body = {
    'values': values
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
    valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
print('{0} cells appended.'.format(result \
                                       .get('updates') \
                                       .get('updatedCells')))
```

Change `value_input_option` to make formulas register as formulas.